# Android on wifi - only local network, no internet

Tags: networking, wi-fi, htc

My phone (HTC One X) can't get internet when connected to my office wifi network.

My office's wifi has no problem for me and my workers.

By default, my phone uses DHCP mode when connected to local network. However, it adamantly picks the same IP that conflicts with another server in the network. In DHCP mode, I get no internet.

I switch my phone to static IP (along with the correct gateway and DNS). Even with a good internal IP address (no conflict, I checked in the router), I still get no access to internet. I used Fing on Android to ping machines within the network successfully, but pinging any domain name at all would fail.

I even tried switch DNS on my phone to 8.8.8.8 and it won't work. Pinging any external IP would fail

I have no problem connecting to my home wifi (DHCP mode) that has the same router model.

I'm out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: I run stock ROM. We have no IT department, it's a small office.

Answer (score 0):

if your phone is working on outside wifi connections, and your office computers are working fine then its probably the proxy. Ask your IT department they should give you a manual proxy address and port to get round the proxy and you should be good to go.

Comment: I deployed a proxy server myself and it work. But it's only a half measure coz I only get internet for certain app (browser, FB, G+) on my phone but not across the entire OS. Appreciate your suggestion though.